# Object-to-array flattening function

Tags: javascript, algorithm, object-oriented, array, recursion

I have written a function that is designed to convert an object into an array of key/pair values ("flattening it") like so:

**Input**

```json
{
  "a": true,
  "b": {
    "c": 500
  }
}
```

**Output**

```json
[
  ["a", true],
  ["b", [
    ["c", 500]
  ]
]
```

Here is the code I have written to do it:

```javascript
function isCyclicObject(object, seenObjects) {
  seenObjects = (seenObjects instanceof Array) ? seenObjects : [];

  if (object instanceof Object) {
    if (seenObjects.indexOf(object) !== -1) {
      return true;
    }

    seenObjects.push(object);

    for (var key in object) {
      if (object.hasOwnProperty(key) && isCyclicObject(object[key], seenObjects)) {
        return true;
      }
    }

    return false;
  }

  return false;
}

function flattenObject(object) {
  if (!(object instanceof Object) || isCyclicObject(object)) {
    return null;
  }

  var flattened = [];

  for (var key in object) {
    var value = object[key];

    if (value instanceof Object) {
      value = flattenObject(value);

      if (value === null) {
        return null;
      }
    }

    flattened.push([key, value]);
  }

  return flattened;
}
```

I don't really have any major concerns over my code, however I would really appreciate having someone review it and point out any mistakes or flaws in my code that I haven't noticed. I'm also not all too familiar with how to lay out my JS code, so I believe that could possibly be improved too.

And here is the code I wrote to test its functionality:

```javascript
function compareArrays(first, second) {
  if (!(first instanceof Array) || !(second instanceof Array)) {
    return false;
  }

  if (first.length != second.length) {
    return false;
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < first.length; i++) {
    var firstValue = first[i],
        secondValue = second[i];

    if (firstValue instanceof Array && secondValue instanceof Array) {
      if (!compareArrays(firstValue, secondValue)) {
        return false;
      }
    } else if (firstValue != secondValue) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}

function testFlattenObject(object, expected) {
  var flattened = flattenObject(object);

  var objectString = JSON.stringify(object),
      expectedString = JSON.stringify(expected),
      flattenedString = JSON.stringify(flattened);

  var failed = false;

  if (object instanceof Object) {
    failed = !compareArrays(flattened, expected);
  } else {
    failed = flattened !== null;
  }

  if (failed) {
    console.error("Test failed for " + objectString + ": expected " + expectedString + " but got " + flattenedString);
  } else {
    console.log("Test passed");
  }
}

testFlattenObject({}, []);

testFlattenObject({
  a: true
}, [
  ["a", true]
]);

testFlattenObject({
  a: true,
  b: {
    c: 500
  }
}, [
  ["a", true],
  ["b", [
    ["c", 500]
  ]]
]);
```

Comment: Your `isCyclicObject` function returns false positives for references to the same substructure. Take for example`var z = {}; isCyclicObject({ a: z. b: z })`. This happens because you're not popping anything off `seenObjects`.

Comment: The code is long.... Eg, you can shorten the flatten method into one line: https://jsfiddle.net/k4apowb7/.  Similar improvements can be made for the other function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess correctness is the most important aspect - as I mentioned in a comment, `isCyclicObject` returns false positives for references to the same substructure.

I don't know if you intended to directly return null if a value is null (in the `flattenObject` function). Seems a little harsh to scrap the whole object if any one of its properties has a null value. I would have assumed the behavior should have been to skip pushing the property to the `flattened` array.

Performance-wise there is some room for improvement:

- the function `isCyclicObject` is called every time the `flattenObject` function is called. This is not necessary - you only need to perform the check for cycles once.
- an array is not the ideal data structure to use for `seenObjects`. I'd pick the native `Set` - don't worry, even IE (11) supports it. Read about it on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set). Plus, to check if something is part of a set you get the neat `set.has(something)` method which is far better looking than `array.indexOf(something) !== -1`.
- `for ... in` is not very optimizable by JavaScript engines and what's more it will cause the whole function it's part of to not be optimized. You can read about this [here](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers#523-the-object-contains-enumerable-array-indices). The other argument against `for ... in` is that it needs to be accompanied by `hasOwnProperty`. I see you're doing that for `isCylicObject` but not for `flattenObject`. Instead of `for ... in` you could use `Object.keys(obj)` which returns an array of the object's own properties directly.

Style-wise:

- don't expose `seenObjects` to the user. If the user accidentally types in a second parameter to `seenObjects` then strange things will happen and debugging it is going to be unpleasant. Instead you can initialise it in a closure like so:

  ```
  function isCyclicObject(object) {
    var seenObjects = []

    // let's shadow the original function
    function isCyclicObject(object) {
      // check every property or and call traverse recursively
      // your original logic, except for the `seenObjects` initialization
    }

    return isCyclicObject(object)
  }
  ```

This way you also eliminate that check which occurs every time, making the traversal faster.

- prefer to use `const` and `let` over `var` unless you're targeting old browsers
- prefer the more functional `forEach/map/some` in your case instead of `for` loops

EDIT:

Don't use `... instanceof Object` to verify if something is an object. Objects with a null prototype will fail that test. Instead use `typeof ... === 'object' && ... !== null

Comment: Just to note, even in the latest browsers. support for `const` and `let` is very iffy. I recommend using a transpiler when using very new features.